# How to influence High Partition distribution

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I am Emperor of Britain, holding all four kingoms, and I have three sons.

I want my player heir to get Ireland and England, and Scotland and Wales to go to the other two.

Currently, my player heir is getting Ireland and Wales.

If I grant Scotland and Wales to my other sons beforehand, does that stop them inheriting England, which will then go to my player heir? Alternatively, if I grant England to my player heir, they should also get Ireland (as it's my primary kingdon) right?

(and a quick aside: the order they're given out appears to be the order in which my line acquired them, right?)

Comment: Pretty sure you can't control who inherits what in case all heirs have claims on the Kingdoms. Except the player heir should inherit the primary title. Though if one of the heirs do something nasty such as leading a rebellion, you can if you defeat them negotiate to have them renounce their claims, if which case they won't inherit.

Answer (score 1):

Your heirs will inherit a set number of titles of each tier (Kingdom, Duchy, County). Granting them a title will count towards inheritance for that tier, so granting them a Kingdom prior to succession will change the title they will inherit. With High partition, three sons, and four Kingdom titles, you *should* keep two and lose one to each son.

An alternate way to ensure the right titles go to your heir would be to enact an elective succession on a Kingdom title where you can direct votes to your player heir. To do this, go to the title and click the "Add Laws" button. This takes the title out of the inheritance "pool" that determines how many each heir receives.

The Succession page on the CK3 wiki is helpful for understanding the various forms of partition.
https://ck3.paradoxwikis.com/Succession

Comment: So if an heir is given a kingdom, they should inherit no further kingdoms (unless they're the primary heir), and only the duchies that belong to that kingdom?

Comment: To further complicate things, I cannot grant any other kingdoms to the primary heir, but I can grant any kingdom to their other heirs. Also heirs can inherit kingdoms without any counties, but I have to give a county to go with it in order to grant one.

Comment: So I tried, and it didn't work. I granted Wales to my second son, and then he was still going to inherit another kingdom, and my primary heir was only going to get one. Made my third take vows to balance it back out.